Chain one agent and two tools in llama index with pgvector
I have the following code that makes me able to ask questions about specifics incidents in my vector store, as well as aggregated metrics from the SQL metadata table. What I would like is to chain both tools, so that if my query is for instance :
What's the reason of the incident that occurs in Paris in 2021 and that implied Seine flood,
The agent would
1/ Query with structured_query the ids of the incidents with criteria city=Paris and date = 2021
2/ Use semantic_search for "Seine flood" on the associated incidents
Or inversely. For the moment this type of query is not correctly handled by the model
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import make_url, create_engine

from llama_index.agent.openai import OpenAIAgent
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index.vector_stores.postgres import PGVectorStore
from llama_index.core import Document, Settings, SQLDatabase, VectorStoreIndex, StorageContext, 
from llama_index.core.tools import QueryEngineTool, ToolMetadata
from llama_index.core.query_engine import NLSQLTableQueryEngine


embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding(
    model="text-embedding-3-small",
    dimensions=1536 ,
    embed_batch_size=20
)
llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-4o")
Settings.embed_model = embed_model
Settings.llm = llm

df = pd.read_pickle('all_incidents.pkl')

def sql_connection():
    connection_string = "postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/incidents"
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
    conn.autocommit = True
    url = make_url(connection_string)
    return url


# Create a SQL database
engine = create_engine(sql_connection())
df.to_sql('incidents', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index='public')

# Create the SQLStructStoreIndex
sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine, include_tables=["incidents"])

# Create documents for the VectorStoreIndex
documents = [
    Document(
        text=row['text'],
        metadata={
            "title": row['title'],
            "city": row['city'],
            "introduction": row['introduction'],
            'level': row['level'],
            "type": row['type'],
            "date": str(row['date']),
        },
    )
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
]


def open_vector_store():
    url = sql_connection()
    db_name = "incidents"
    vector_store = PGVectorStore.from_params(
        database=db_name,
        host=url.host,
        password=url.password,
        port=url.port,
        user=url.username,
        table_name="incidents_vectors",
        embed_dim=1536,
        hnsw_kwargs={
            "hnsw_m": 16,
            "hnsw_ef_construction": 64,
            "hnsw_ef_search": 40,
            "hnsw_dist_method": "vector_cosine_ops",
        },
    )
    return vector_store


vector_store = open_vector_store()
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    documents, strage_context=storage_context, show_progress=True
)
vector_query_engine = index.as_query_engine()


sql_query_engine = NLSQLTableQueryEngine(
    sql_database=sql_database, tables=["incidents"], llm=llm
)

query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=vector_query_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
                name= "semantic_search",
                description= "Returns informations about specific incidents"
        )
    ),
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=sql_query_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
                name= "structured_query",
                description= "Allows queries for synthesis on the number of incidents, their distribution etc"
        ),
    ),
]

agent = OpenAIAgent.from_tools(query_engine_tools, verbose=True)
agent.chat_repl()


